# How to add a back button that hides when WebView cannot go back

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uiwebview, webkit

My app loads a WebView. I've embedded in a Navigation Controller and added a Bar Button Item to be my back button...

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

var refController:UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    
    @IBAction func backwardsButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        webView.goBack()
    }
    

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        
        let url = "https://www.google.com/"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        self.webView.load(request)
```

It all works fine, but I'd like to hide the back button so it only shows when the WebView loads new content. For example, the  app opens on google.com and the back button is hidden, but when the user searches for something and loads a new page, the button appears.

I then want the button to hide again when the user taps back and ends back at google.com.

Any help or advice? I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 5):

You can check for the `webView`'s `canGoBack` property to set your `backButton`'s `isHidden` property as `true` or `false` in the `webView(_:,didFinish:)` method.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    //...
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) { // triggers when loading is complete
        backButton.isHidden = !webView.canGoBack
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code should work:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        
        let url = "https://www.google.com/"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        self.webView.load(request)
    }

    
    @IBAction func backwardsButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if (self.webView.canGoBack) {
            self.webView.goBack()
        }
    }
}
```

You can also implement the forward button:

```
@IBAction func forwardButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if (self.webView.canGoForward) {
        self.webView.goForward()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the button still doesn't hide when the WebView cannot go back. I was hoping the button would only appear when the page can actually go back, otherwise hide itself from the Navigation Controller.

Comment: This response fails to answer the question.